# What could be causing a continuous JSON request for new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

We have deployed a Rails 3.0.3 app and are seeing the following error:

```
Started GET "/session/new" for 74.222.223.113 at Fri Feb 25 16:22:30 -0800 2011
  Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Completed   in 25ms
** [Hoptoad] Success: Net::HTTPOK
** [Hoptoad] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.8.7] [Rails: 3.0.4] [Env: production]
** [Hoptoad] Response from Hoptoad: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notice>
  <error-id type="integer">4066770</error-id>
  <id type="integer">716757790</id>
</notice>

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template sessions/new with {:formats=>[:json, :js, "*/*"], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rhtml, :builder, :erb, :prawn_xxx, :rxml, :prawn, :prawn_dsl, :rjs]}
```

It always comes from the same IP address and every 4 seconds or so. Is there any way of figuring out what could be generating this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that Hoptoad can help you debug this issue!

1. Open up the Hoptoad error for one of
   these requests.
2. Click on the "Environment" tab
3. Find the "HTTP_REFERER" variable

This will tell you what page in your app generated this.  From there you should be able to reproduce the issue or figure out what's happening.

My guess is that you have a JSON request that requires being logged in.  Something on the page is hitting that url (ie: http://yourapp.com/users/secret.json) and being redirected to your login page (sessions/new) with the existing request format (JSON).  However, there is no JSON formatted login template, producing the exception you see.

The root cause will be in the JSON request being loaded.

You will probably want to update your authenticity check for logins to silently fail or return a 403 status for JSON or non-HTML requests.